# Python Sudoku Generator infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop, sudoku

I tried to create a program that generates a filled sudoku grid, but for some reason I get an infinite loop after it generates a few lines and it never outputs a finished grid. Every time it generates a different number of correct rows and after a that it just repeats over and over again, without creating any new rows.

This is my code:

```
import random


def generate_sudoku():
    sudoku_grid_generated = [[0 for _ in range(9)] for _ in range(9)]
    is_valid_grid = False
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            while True:
                i_counter = 0
                j_counter = 0
                valid_grid = 0
                generated_number = random.randint(1, 9)
                if 0 <= row <= 2 and 0 <= col <= 2:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[0][0], sudoku_grid_generated[0][1], sudoku_grid_generated[0][2],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[1][0], sudoku_grid_generated[1][1], sudoku_grid_generated[1][2],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[2][0], sudoku_grid_generated[2][1], sudoku_grid_generated[2][2]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1

                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                elif 3 <= row <= 5 and 0 <= col <= 2:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[3][0], sudoku_grid_generated[3][1], sudoku_grid_generated[3][2],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[4][0], sudoku_grid_generated[4][1], sudoku_grid_generated[4][2],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[5][0], sudoku_grid_generated[5][1], sudoku_grid_generated[5][2]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                elif 6 <= row <= 8 and 0 <= col <= 2:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[6][0], sudoku_grid_generated[6][1], sudoku_grid_generated[6][2],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[7][0], sudoku_grid_generated[7][1], sudoku_grid_generated[7][2],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[8][0], sudoku_grid_generated[8][1], sudoku_grid_generated[8][2]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                elif 0 <= row <= 2 and 3 <= col <= 5:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[0][3], sudoku_grid_generated[0][4], sudoku_grid_generated[0][5],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[1][3], sudoku_grid_generated[1][4], sudoku_grid_generated[1][5],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[2][3], sudoku_grid_generated[2][4], sudoku_grid_generated[2][5]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                elif 3 <= row <= 5 and 3 <= col <= 5:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[3][3], sudoku_grid_generated[3][4], sudoku_grid_generated[3][5],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[4][3], sudoku_grid_generated[4][4], sudoku_grid_generated[4][5],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[5][3], sudoku_grid_generated[5][4], sudoku_grid_generated[5][5]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                elif 3 <= row <= 5 and 6 <= col <= 8:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[3][6], sudoku_grid_generated[3][7], sudoku_grid_generated[3][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[4][6], sudoku_grid_generated[4][7], sudoku_grid_generated[4][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[5][6], sudoku_grid_generated[5][7], sudoku_grid_generated[5][8]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                elif 0 <= row <= 2 and 6 <= col <= 8:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[0][6], sudoku_grid_generated[0][7], sudoku_grid_generated[0][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[1][6], sudoku_grid_generated[1][7], sudoku_grid_generated[1][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[2][6], sudoku_grid_generated[2][7], sudoku_grid_generated[2][8]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                elif 3 <= row <= 5 and 6 <= col <= 8:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[3][6], sudoku_grid_generated[3][7], sudoku_grid_generated[3][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[4][6], sudoku_grid_generated[4][7], sudoku_grid_generated[4][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[5][6], sudoku_grid_generated[5][7], sudoku_grid_generated[5][8]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                elif 6 <= row <= 8 and 6 <= col <= 8:
                    if generated_number not in [sudoku_grid_generated[6][6], sudoku_grid_generated[6][7], sudoku_grid_generated[6][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[7][6], sudoku_grid_generated[7][7], sudoku_grid_generated[7][8],
                                                sudoku_grid_generated[8][6], sudoku_grid_generated[8][7], sudoku_grid_generated[8][8]]:
                        if generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row]:
                            i_counter += 1
                            print(i_counter)
                        for r in range(9):
                            if sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] != generated_number:
                                j_counter += 1
                        if i_counter == 1 and j_counter == 9:
                            sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
                            break

                    else:
                        continue
                for rows in range(9):
                    for cols in range(9):
                        if sudoku_grid_generated[rows][cols] != 0:
                            valid_grid += 1
                if valid_grid == 81:
                    is_valid_grid = True
                if is_valid_grid:
                    break
                for p in sudoku_grid_generated:
                    print(p)
    for p in sudoku_grid_generated:
        print(p)

generate_sudoku()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try running your code through a debugger?

Comment: There are at least 4 loops in your code (I stopped counting after that). Which one is infinite?

Comment: Normally I’d advise against changing code before you finish troubleshooting it, but assuming this is a personal project just for fun, you really need to break your code up into functions / methods for it to be readable. Hard to read code is a great place for bugs to hide, and code that’s one long complicated function is hard to read. You’re also a lot more likely for people to be willing to help you with it—that’s not intended to be rude, but it’s hard for others to read too and it’s asking a lot for them to wade thru hard to read code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you will reach an infinite loop almost for sure.
By putting random numbers in your table its very (very) likely you write a wrong number.
That is: a number that makes your Sudoku impossible to resolve.
By the time you write the wrong number, it might seem a legit number because there are too many free position to notice the Sudoku is impossible.
In your `while True` you have no way of reach a `break` if there are no valid numbers for you current `row`, `col` position.
When would you know you have tried all the possibilities?
Instead of looping and asking a random integer every time pick a number randomly from 1 to 9 and break the loop as soon as you have tried all the possibilities.
`for generated_number in random.sample(range(1, 10), 9):`

If you complete this loop, this means you have an impossible Sudoku: you will have to change some number already placed.
Because of the nested loops in your function this seems very difficult to do.
I cannot suggest you a particular method because that will depend on how much Python and OOP you know.
A pure functional approach can be done with a simple recursive function.
This popular video shows how to do it: [Python Sudoku Solver - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM)

If you prefer to figure it out on your own here is a hint: a Sudoku without 0s is always possible to solve. Put a random number and ask to yourself whether the resulting Sudoku is solvable or not.

---

Not related to your question, but there is a simple formula to iterate every square given a position `row`, `col`.
This way you don't have to repeat your code.
In summary I would substitute your whole `while True` loop like so:

```
for generated_number in random.sample(range(1, 10), 9):
                
    if (generated_number not in (sudoku_grid_generated[(row // 3) * 3 + i][(col // 3) * 3 + j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)) and
        generated_number not in sudoku_grid_generated[row] and
        generated_number not in (sudoku_grid_generated[r][col] for r in range(9))):
        sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] = generated_number
        break

    if all(sudoku_grid_generated[row][col] != 0 for row in range(9) for col in range(9)):
        break
    for p in sudoku_grid_generated:
        print(p)
```